# How to extract values from queryset objects in python?

Tags: python, django, forms, list, django-queryset

I'm trying to compare values to each other for a quiz in django. I'm using POST data for object data and trying to compare each other.

Current code:

```
answerList = []
answerList2 = []
for i in Question.objects.filter(related_quiz = examid):
    answerList.append(i.answer)

form = EditQuizForm()
form = EditQuizForm(request.POST)

if request.method == "POST":
    form = EditQuizForm(request.POST)
    submittedObject = request.POST.copy()
    newList = (dict(submittedObject.lists()))
    values = newList.values()
    for i in values:
        answerList2.append(i)

    print(answerList)
    print(answerList2)
```

This returns the values:

```
      ['A', 'D']
      [['A'], ['D']]
```

However, I cannot iterate over these to compare them as they are not the same. I do not how get answerList2 to appear like answerList1 so i can compare the values. Any help would be appreciated as i am fairly new to python/django.

Comment: From what I understand you want to compare the values of `answerList` with `answerList2`. That's right ?

Comment: That's correct (e.g. Compare 'A' to 'A', 'D' to 'D')

Comment: Can you try printing the "newList" object & "submittedObject" and show us the output for the following? Will be helpful in debugging your code.

Comment: Submitted object:      <QueryDict: {'1': ['A'], '2': ['D']}>
newList:     {'1': ['A'], '2': ['D']}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop and compare the values of answerList with the value of index 0 of answerList2

```
def compareLists(answerList, answerList2):
   for i in range(len(answerList)):
      if answerList[i] != answerList2[i][0]:
         break
   else:
      return True
   return False
```

When an item is different the loop will be broken with break and the function will return False. Otherwise it will not exit with break and return True.

I hope I have helped :)

Comment: Just a small typo in that code, the second answerList in missing a '2'. Tested it and it works though, thankyou!